# show that a graph with minimum vertex at least 2 must contain a cycle

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph such that $\delta \geq 2$, then $G$ contains a cycle. $\delta$ denotes the minimum vertex degree of graph $G$.

Comment: Suppose $G$ has no cycles. Then $G$ is a forest. Forests have trees. Trees have ___ (or the tree is a single vertex). ___ have degree __$<2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Imagine a depth first search defining your path where no edge is used more that once. Then whatever vertex you start with, and whatever distinct vertices you go to after that, you will always have a vertex you can visit along an unused edge from the last vertex in the path to extend the path as long as you have no repeated vertices in your current path. But your graph is finite.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  Prove the following lemma:

> If a graph is a tree with $n\geq 2$ vertices, it has at least two vertices of degree one (called leaves).

Use the contrapositive statement:

> If a graph with $n\geq 2$ vertices does not have at least two vertices of degree one, it is not a tree.

Restrict your attention to one of the connected components and note that it is not a tree.

Finish by using one of the many definitions for a tree pertaining to existence of cycles.